# How to change integration order in a double integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

> Change the order of integration in the double integral:
>   $$
> \int\limits_1^2dx\int\limits_{\ln x}^{3x}f(x;y)dy
> $$

I plotted a picture to make this problem easier. And I managed to see that $0\leqslant y\leqslant 6$. However, I couldn't find the boundaries for $x$.
Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Start by drawing a picture with two curves: $y=\ln x$ and $y=3x$ between $x=1$ and $x=2$. You will notice that you would need to split the inner integral into several domains

Comment: Oh, yes. Thank you! Is it $\int\limits_0^{\ln2}dy\int\limits_{1}^{e^y}fdx+\int\limits_{\ln2}^{3}dy\int\limits_{1}^{2}fdx+\int\limits_3^{6}dy\int\limits_{y/3}^{2}fdx$ ?

Comment: Glad I could help. And the limits look OK